# Unity 3D Game Changing Screen Orientation in realtime causes touch coordinates to become wrong

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-orientation

My game has default Landscape left orientation but I have to make one scene with Portrait orientation. So I used

`Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;`

This works perfectly in most of Android devices but I got some unusual bug using a Xiaomi MI 6 device. This rotates the screen but the touch positions of each objects are at random locations in the screen. If I press home button and again resume the game from recent apps, everything works fine.

**[Update]** 
Creating a demo project with just few buttons works fine but I cannot find the problem in my current project. I have only used facebook login plugin in my current project.

Comment: perphaps the touch events are still mapped for landscape?

Comment: We need some information on how you're retrieving the touch positions.

Comment: This is working fine for most of the android devices. I got this issue in xiaomi MI6 phone (till now) and I haven't tested in IOS devies. Just a simple UI Button touch position changes when the orientation is changed.

Comment: Inside my project I have used `SetResolution(width, height, true);` to set fix resolution and forgot to change it while changing the orientation because without changing the resolution it was working on my few test devices(samsung devices). I just have to remove the SetResolution() method and problem solved.